# Perl, graph.pm, directed graphs, ordering vertices based on edges

Tags: perl, graph

I'm using graph.pm and building a multi-edged graph. Each vertex is a dna sequence id and each directed edge represents the relative position of two dna sequences along a transcript ( RNA sequence ). 
For example, if you have an RNA sequence and you BLAT it ( align it ) against a dna assembly file containing millions of dna sequences of varying lengths you may find that the gene from which the RNA was translated got split in to two or more different sequences in your DNA assembly. 
The good news is that you can use that RNA alignment information to reunite the gene by ordering dna sequences according to their alignment with the RNA. Hence the need for a directed graph. Actually, a single gene region can give rise to multiple RNA so we use a multigraph to capture this information.

Given a dna assembly with the following dna sequences in no particular order:

```
my ( `$dna_ff, $dna_fh, $dna_kl, $dna_dq, $dna_cg, $dna_rr, $dna_er, $dna_pz, $dna_aq, $dna_ne` ) = ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
```

There's a split gene represented by the following order of sequences:

```
$dna_aq, $dna_dq, $dna_er, $dna_ne, $dna_kl ( 9, 4, 7, 10, 3 )
```

So I create a simple multiedge graph:

```
my $g = Graph->new(multiedged => 1);
```

And I add the edges. However, this gene is represented by multiple RNA that use different exons so the alignment of the dna sequences to the RNA sequences for this gene is not necessarily a simple thing to interpret.
For example,

```
For RNA_1:
    $dna_aq, $dna_dq, $dna_kl
For RNA_2:
    $dna_dq, $dna_ne
For DNA_3:
    $dna_er, $dna_kl
```

If I use RNA_1 as the basis for ordering we'd miss `$dna_er` and `$dna_ne`.
Taking into consideration RNA_2 and RNA_3 we can see that it's not possible to tell if `$dna_ne` comes before or after `$dna_kl`, just that they both come after `$dna_dq`. Similarly, we know that `$dna_er` comes before `$dna_kl` but we don't know what sequence it comes after, if any.

```
$dna_dq --> $dna_kl
$dna_dq --> $dna_ne
$dna_er --> $dna_kl
```

However, suppose we have a fourth RNA telling us that `$dna_ne --> $dna_kl`. Now we know that `$dna_ne` sits between `$dna_dq` and `$dna_kl`. We still can't place `$dna_er` but at least we've been able to come closer to the correct ordering by combining the information from multiple RNA sequences.

So let's add the edges:

```
$g->add_edges($dna_aq, $dna_dq, $dna_dq, $dna_kl );
$g->add_edges($dna_dq, $dna_ne);
$g->add_edges($dna_er, $dna_kl);
$g->add_edges($dna_ne, $dna_kl);

# 9-4, 4-3
# 4-10
# 7-3
# 10-3
```

The the correct order is 9, 4, 10, and 3. We can't place 7.

```
print "The graph is $g\n";

The graph is 10-3,4-10,4-3,7-3,9-4
```

What I want is to return the correct rder of vertices from the graph. I tried a topological sort.

```
my @ts = $g->topological_sort;
print qq[@ts\n];
```

But this prints: `7 9 4 10 3`.

So this is not what I want. The 7 in this case should not be in the list of ordered vertices because we cannot determine it's position reltive to the other sequences.

QUESTION: Does anyone know what this type of problem is called. More importantly, how do I return an array of vertices that includes only those vertices whose relative positions can be fully determined? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like this would simply be the longest path through the graph. So  I'd need to return the ordered vertices of such a path. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: graph_diameter() should return the longest path. Honestly, though, my last run-in with graphs has been a while, so you will have to check the specifics.